# Java: Need some way to shorten this code

Tags: java, android

I have this piece of code that I would like to shorten...

```
    PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
    final List<PackageInfo> appinstall = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    PackageManager pro = context.getPackageManager();
    final List<PackageInfo> apllprovides = pro.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);
```

I am seriously irritated to do this again and again to add new flag permissions, and I need to do it a couple of times, is there a shorter method in which I could put all the flags on the same definition...???

Let me put it this way, can I do this...??? (of course this gives an error, but something similar..)

```
    PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager();
    final List<PackageInfo> appinstall = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS).addFlag(PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);
```

Comment: I am sorry if I am missing something obvious, I can be pretty dumb that way... :P

Comment: Im not sure if I understand you correctly, but why are you doing this? Do you want to add permissions to your activity? Then you can do this in your manifest file.

Comment: No I trying to retrieve the permissions from the packages installed. Apart from permission I also intend to retrieve content providers, services, etc etc.. Each time I need to set the flag for the package, so I was wondering if there was a way to assign multiple flags on the same declaration...

Comment: Please post what error did you get?

Comment: Its solved... Well there was syntax error when I did that, Ck below posted the solution to my question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it's the same syntax as C# and the flags are set properly, you could do this:

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager(); 
final List<PackageInfo> appinstall = 
    p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS | 
                                      PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void usegetPackageInfo(){
    // 
    final ListView lw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    PackageManager p = lw.getContext().getPackageManager(); 
    final List<PackageInfo> appinstall = 
        p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS | 
                                          PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);
    final TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Iterator it = appinstall.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        PackageInfo rf = (PackageInfo) it.next();
        tw.append(rf.toString());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the android Documentation:
for permissions:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html

for providers:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html

Before that Completely study about [manifest documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)