# How can I get all applications that have the internet permission in Android Applications?

Tags: java, android, wifi

How can I get all applications that have the internet permission in Android? 
How can I do that? 
any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate over all installed apps, using the [`PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_PERMISSIONS) flag. You can then check if the internet permission is in the returned value.

Sample code (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3280756/1438733)):

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager(); 
final List<PackageInfo> apps = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
for (PackageInfo pkg : apps) {
    for (String permission : pkg.requestedPermissions) {
        // Check if permission is the internet permission
    }
}
```