# Android M: Can you programatically get the full set of permissions an app would like?

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

This isn't the same as the ones an app has been currently granted - that might be a subset of the ones it would like in total.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280632/java-need-some-way-to-shorten-this-code) shows how to get the currently granted set. Before Android M, that's the full set because it wouldn't have been installed unless the user had granted all of the ones it wanted. Under Android M however, the user can choose which to grant, and change at any time after installation. I'd like the full set an app would like as listed in it's manifest.

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: You can get the full set. But the user can always alt-tab and revoke some of the permissions he granted you earlier, and toggle them as he likes.

Comment: "This shows how to get the currently granted set" -- I would expect `GET_PERMISSIONS` to return all that are in the manifest, regardless of whether the user granted them or not. [The `requestedPermissions` field](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions) is documented as "This list includes all permissions requested, even those that were not granted or known by the system at install time." A separate `requestedPermissionsFlags` has the grant status. Do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: I've no evidence either way, just trying various tests on M and pre-M devices. What you say sounds about right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CommonsWare commented, [`PackageInfo.requestedPermissions`](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions) contains an *"Array of all `<uses-permission>` tags included under `<manifest>`, or null if there were none."*

I've tested this on a device running Android M, and the output I got included the permissions from all `<uses-permission>` tags regardless of whether those permissions had been granted or not, just as expected.

A minimal example for testing this:

```
try {
    PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.example.foo", PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    for (String perm : pi.requestedPermissions) {
        Log.e("Foo", perm);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`adb shell dumpsys package packagename` will give you the permissions info requested by the app with  `packagename`