# How to create a listview with 2 columns showing all installed android apps and the permissions along with it?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-intent

I'm pretty newbie to Android development (2 days old).

I intend to create an app that list all the currently installed applications in the device and a column beside each of those results showing the permissions granted. I understand that conventionally a listView has 1 column , how do I make another column ?

I'm open to other ideas as well (like perhaps another intent when i click the installed application name ?)

Below is my code thus far which shows all installed applications :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextSwitcher;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class PopAnalysis extends Activity{
    ListView appList;
    private TextSwitcher mSwitcher;
    TextView myText;
    private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popupanalysis);
        appList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewApp);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN,null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
            results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
            System.out.println(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }
        appList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
        appList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int itemposition = position;
                String value = (String) appList.getItemAtPosition(position);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Following are my XML codes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">



     <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewApp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textViewAnalysis"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_appname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_apppermissions"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make your Listview with Customadpter

Comment: could you elaborate more ? perhaps modify my code or sth as an example ?

Comment: Have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280632/java-need-some-way-to-shorten-this-code).

Comment: do you got it worked ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you need load apps list and permission for every apps. I do it inside Activity.onCreate to simplify example. The better way to do it inside AsyncTask

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

        final List<Pair<String, List<String>>> appsWithPermission = new ArrayList<>();

        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        final List<ResolveInfo> apps = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo info : apps) {
            final ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo;
            final String appName = (String) applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager);

            final List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

            if (appName != null) {

                try {
                    final PackageInfo packageInfo = packageManager.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
                    final String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

                    if (requestedPermissions != null) {
                        permissions.addAll(Arrays.asList(requestedPermissions));
                    }

                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            appsWithPermission.add(new Pair<>(appName, permissions));
        }

        final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        final AppsAdapter appsAdapter = new AppsAdapter(this, appsWithPermission);
        listView.setAdapter(appsAdapter);
    }
}
```

Secondly you need xml layout `list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_appname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_apppermissions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and finally `AppsAdapter.java`

```
public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private List<Pair<String, List<String>>> mAppsWithPermission;

    public AppsAdapter(Context context, List<Pair<String, List<String>>> appsWithPermission) {
        mContext = context;
        mAppsWithPermission = appsWithPermission;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView appName;
        public TextView appPermissions;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mAppsWithPermission.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mAppsWithPermission.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mAppsWithPermission.get(position).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.appName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_appname);
            holder.appPermissions = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_apppermissions);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Pair<String, List<String>> item = mAppsWithPermission.get(position);

        holder.appName.setText(item.first);
        holder.appPermissions.setText(item.second.toString());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: not working. especially the adapter it returned tons of error. please refer to my question and edit your solution again accordingly. Do bear in mind I used "public class PopAnalysis extends Activity{}"  and not "public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {". Please re-tailor your solution to my structure please thanks

Comment: "final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);" <--- list_view missing in the .xml file? should I be adding a new list_view parameter ?

Comment: R.id.listViewApp in your xml layout

Comment: there are some formatting layouts at the moment. if you solved it you will get the bounty !

There were overlapping texts currently. Im not familiar with UI design. Could you propose an edited XML ? I have edited my questions with the xml file

Comment: Just remove from Activity `RelativeLayout` anything except  `ListView`. App names and permissions list are inside other layout witch inflated inside adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've already figured out how to get a list of all installed applications and their respective permissions, which is good. In order to make a ListView with multiple columns, though, you'll need to implement a ListViewAdapter.

A really great resource for figuring out how to do this can be found [here](http://techlovejump.com/android-multicolumn-listview/).

If you're confused about anything on that link, or something doesn't work, let me know.

**Code:**

**PopAnalysis.java**

```
public class PopAnalysis extends Activity {
    public static final String FIRST_COLUMN = "First";
    public static final String SECOND_COLUMN = "Second";

    ListView appList;
    private TextSwitcher mSwitcher;
    TextView myText;
    private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popupanalysis);

        appList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewApp);
        HashMap<String,String> t1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        t1.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "App 1");
        t1.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "Permission 1");
        list.add(t1);

        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public static final String FIRST_COLUMN = "First";
    public static final String SECOND_COLUMN = "Second";

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Activity activity;
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;


    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
        super();
        this.activity=activity;
        this.list=list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView == null){

            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.column_row_layout, null);

            txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.application);
            txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.permissions);

        }

        HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
        txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**column_row_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/application"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/permissions"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In PopAnalysis.java I added only one entry to simply show how it's done. Certainly you shouldn't have any issues implementing the data you want into it.

Comment: is there a way you could suggest the answer by posting the recommended solution edits into my question that i posted?

Comment: Yeah, check my edit. Although I didn't make it list out all apps and their permissions, I added in a single row so that you could see how it was done. It shouldn't be much more code at all to add in what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 2 column listview , you can also try ExpandableListView. Clicking on the item with expand a detail view just below to it.
detail view will contain the permissions of that app.

[Expandable Listview Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

BTW, there is no way in SDK's listview to have multiple column. What you can do is to have a pseudo-multicolumn list view like using multiple textview(or other kind of view) in the same row. In that case you will need to make a custom adapter for your list view and a custom row layout file.

If you really want to have something multi-column, then either 3rd party libraries or `TableLayout` is your only option.

[TableLayout tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74&aaid=98)

Comment: is there a way you could suggest the answer by posting the recommended solution edits into my question that i posted?

Answer (score 0):

to make two column listview you have to implement custom listview. please [read this link](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html)

in program_list.xml instead of imageview take textview it will resolve your problem.