# How to get app requested permissions and app name in two columns

Tags: java, android, listview, permissions

I was looking for an old question that i am no longer able to find in this website.

It showed how to create an Android java-based application with a list with two panes in which the first pane showed the list of app names, and the second showed the related app permissions asked, like the scheme before:

[App name1] [App permissions1]

[App name2] [App permissions2]

Thank you so much if you are able to find it, or to send me the same code, I've spent some hours to find it without success.

Regards

Comment: Found it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35814207/how-to-create-a-listview-with-2-columns-showing-all-installed-android-apps-and-t thanks anyway!